# How does Tomoe's father know who kenshin is or that they were even married?

Tags: rurouni-kenshin

In the manga Oibore in the fallen district (slums) ends up revealing who he is when asked why he helped Kenshin by telling the people there its his daughters husband who was there when she died.  But how did he know? Kenshin was a top secret assassin and his identity was kept secret to most of the public. How did he even know they got married (it happened in the mountains away from anyone) or Tomoe died while kenshin was there (the only people who would know, kenshin killed and maybe the higher up imperialists)?

It was stated he abandoned the family after his wife died so he wouldn't have had any contact with her or Enishi.  Enishi doesn't even meet him until after his fight with Kenshin, even then it is implied he doesn't really know who he is.

Comment: so Kenshin kills someone boyfriend and that married someone . . .

Yandere much :v

Answer (score 2):

Tomoe knew that Kenshin was her fiance's assassin. She moved to Kyoto, desperate to find him. So we can assume that the rest of the family knew about Kenshin too.

When Kenshin kills, he delivers the "Tenshu", a signature for the crimes, that identifies the faction responsible for the murders. Kenshin's reputation among the Ishin Shishi and their ennemies was increasing (remember that the Shinsen Gumi has a physical description of him before actually meeting Kenshin).

So Mr Yukishiro knows that his daughter's fiance was killed by the Ishin Shishi's assassin, and later on, that assassin became famously known has a man with red hair and 2 scars across his left cheek. Even if Kenshin's name was unknown to most, his appearance and skill was becoming a legend.

Now, how would he know about Tomoe's wedding? She wrote to Enishi, once they moved close to Ootsu. That is why Enishi meets them in the mountain (and he already knows that Kenshin is responsible for her fiance's death). We can assume that Tomoe's father learnt about her wedding from Enishi.

Source: Manga + the OVA Rurouni Kenshin Tsuioku Hen

Answer (score 0):

Isika the guy who cleans up after Kenshin's assassinations is a spy.  He knows everything about Kenshin.  He also tries to weaken Kenshin emotionally to get him killed when he goes after Tomoe.